# I want to put the points on the google map, but it always has something wrong for the last line:

Tags: r

I want to put the points on the google map, but it always has something wrong for the last line:

```
p <- get_map(location = 'Illinois',zoom = 8)
ggmap(p)

# this line will have error,thanks
p + geom_point(data=lat_long, aes(long, lat),color = 'red',size =3)

Error in Ops.raster(p, geom_point(data = lat_long, aes(long, lat), color = "red", : operator not meaningful for raster objects
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do something like this:

```
library(dismo)
g <- gmap("Illinois")
x <- geocode("Springfield, Illinois")
plot(g, interpolate=T)
points(Mercator(x[1, c("longitude", "latitude")]), pch=20, col="red", cex=2)
```